# .htaccess rule to load static file if the REQUEST_URI based path to file exists

Tags: .htaccess

So I am having a website and I managed to write the .htaccess rule for the index page, which goes something like:

```
#my .htaccess file lives under the %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/site/www  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_URL} ^$   RewriteCond
%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/site/www/static/index.html -f   RewriteRule ^$
static/index.html [L]
```

Which basically is checking on every request of the index page (http://mywebsite.dev) and is loading it from a folder, called static and from a file, called index.html

so far so good, but I was trying to make it work for per say the blog page.
So in that case we have http://mywebsite.dev/blog

I was debugging in my php script the $_SERVER variable so I am pretty sure what I have there and I was expecting this to work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/site/www/static%{REQUEST_URI}/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ static/$1/index.html [L]
```

but it is not working. So the idea here is - if a folder with the name, in this case blog - exists and if in that folder there is an index.html file - load the page from there, and also if there are no query strings.

I also tried with the second line to look like

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/site/www/static/%{REQUEST_URI}/index.html -f
```

and tried many other things, but it is not working. It could be something really small, or something really big that I am missing, so if someone has a better clue what could be the problem please help me out with this :)

Comment: What is the location of your .htaccess?

Comment: as I wrote in the description (as comment):#my .htaccess file lives under the %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/site/www   so it is one level under the static folder, in the www folder.

Comment: Is it %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/site/www or just /site/www ?

Comment: it is the very same folder that is one level below the static folder - I just wrote it with Document_Root to avoid confusion